# comparing sum of two array element individually

Tags: java, arrays, sum, compare

We are having two diff arrays i.e **array1** & **array2**. Find their sum individually and compare. 
their sum and print **'-1'** if the sum of first array is less than the 
second array else print **'1'**.

```
int array1[] = new int[3]; // array one
   int array2[] = new int[3];  // array two
   int sum1= 0, sum2= 0;

   for(int i=0; i<=2; i++){
     array1[i] = scanner.nextInt();   // storing value by user in first array
     array2[i] = scanner.nextInt();   // storing value by user in second array
     }

   for(int a1 : array1){ 
      sum1 += a1;    // sum of array
     } 
   for(int a2 : array2){ 
      sum2 += a2;   // sum of array2
     }  

   if(sum1<sum2){
       System.out.print("-1");}  //print -1 if sum1 is less than sum2
    else{
       System.out.println("1");}
```

I am trying to do this program as compact as possible but i don't know how to do this. 
     Can anyone tell me the compact program for this code

Comment: you can add the inputs as soon as they come.

Comment: You can replace last four lines with `System.out.println(sum1<sum2 ? "-1" : "1")`. Anyway if your program ***works correctly*** and you are looking for ways to improve it then your question is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is the order of the input correct? I would expect first the first array and then the second, not interleaved elements.

Comment: Thanks Adit.....It works good

Answer (score 1):

You can replace your 3 loops with a single loop :

```
for(int i=0; i<=2; i++){
    array1[i] = scanner.nextInt();   // storing value by user in first array
    array2[i] = scanner.nextInt();   // storing value by user in second array
    sum1 += array1[i];
    sum2 += array2[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int sum1 = Arrays.stream(array1).sum();
int sum2 = Arrays.stream(array2).sum();
int result = Integer.compare(sum1, sum2); //-1, 0 or 1
System.out.println("" + result);
```

Or shorter:

```
System.out.println("" + Integer.compare(Arrays.stream(array1).sum(), Arrays.stream(array2).sum()));
```